# How to add username to netbeans code templates

Tags: php, netbeans

I am trying to add ${user} to my code templates but its only outputting 'user'
Is there a way to set this? Or any suggestions?
Ideally I would like to add date and project name as well?
I know I can add the ${user} to file templates but it doesn't work in code templates

This is a similar issue [NetBeans Code Templates ${date}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226988/netbeans-code-templates-date)

Answer (score 1):

You just hace to use the `default` attribute:

Lets say you crate a new template named *license* with the following content:

```
/*
* All rights reserved.
* Created by ${user default="Keni-Williams"}.
*/
```

Then everytime you write *license* and press tab will appear

```
/*
* All rights reserved.
* Created by Keni-Williams
*/
```

With the `Keny Williams` selected in case you want to change it.